# How can I make bezier curves in Inkscape default to smooth nodes instead of corner nodes?

Tags: inkscape

When I draw a bezier curve the nodes default to corner nodes, how can I make it default to smooth nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not click with the pen, drag every node to the wanted tangent direction. Be sure you have Bezier drawing mode ON, not for ex. "Draw straight line segments"

[image]